# PPTPD Couldn't open the /dev/ppp device: Permission denied

Tags: vpn, permissions, pptpd

I cannot connect to my pptpd server, because it fails to send LCP: Config-Requests to my client. I found the problem, it was located in syslog

```
 Jan 14 03:45:38 mightyowl3 pppd[22256]: Couldn't open the /dev/ppp device: Permission denied
```

can someone please help me fix this...

Extra stuff:

I did

```
chown root
chmod 777
```

on it.

Answer (score 1):

What is the permission on /dev/ppp?  Who owns /dev/ppp?  What is the group membership of /dev/ppp?  What is the username/group under which pptpd being run as?

Providing and analyzing at least this information would help you and perhaps allow us to direct you to the right place to fix this problem.

Comment: how can I get the permissions on /dev/ppp

Comment: `ls -ll /dev/ppp` from a shell window

Answer (score 1):

Some VPS has the configuration of enable PPP service, so you can check it and enable the PPP item. The default settings may be disabled, this can cause error:

```
Couldn't open the /dev/ppp device: No such file or directory
```

[vps config for ppp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPxnY.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the user running the pppd process cannot access to the device. Probably you need to add the user at least to the group of /dev/ppp